# Using a custom Adapter for multiple ListViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android development and I was coding with ListView with a custom adapter. So far so good, then I wanted to use the same adapter with more than one listview, is that ok?

And when I override the method getView(), then I use the same resource to show the views (eg. `R.id.show_view`).  Can I use different layouts in the same adapter? I don't know how to accomplish that.

I dont have the code here, sorry, it's more a question of whether it's a good practice to use the same adapter (eg. ArrayAdapter) to match various ListViews.

Comment: what do you mean by **different layout in the same adapter?**

Comment: in your adapter, getItemViewType() and getViewTypeCount() must match the number of different view types (i.e. layouts) that you use in getView().  So using the same adapter class can be done, but beware these complexities.

Comment: thanks, im looking that, but on every examples its seem like the adapter is for only one listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse class, but no instance of adapter.   And you can create different views for every entry. But for sake of performance,  you shall reuse view supplied to getView() whenever possible

Comment: Take a look to this link (http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-simple-listview-1/)
Its not exactly what i wanted but its helps me lot to understanding how to manipulate ListViews. Its go from simple listviews to more complex, very useful.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot share an Adapter instance between ListViews ? I see nothing preventing it...